# Cannot isolate Raspberry Pi from the other circuit using optocoupler. Why not?

Tags: opto-isolator, serial-bus

I'm sending data (Tx1-D) and command (Tx2-C) communication from Raspberry Pi 3 at baud rate 115200. I tried to isolate the RPi from the other circuits by using optocoupler as in the diagram but it doesn't work.  I tried different values for R2, R3, R4 and R5 (ranges from 200 ohm to 100k) but all failed. Why?

Note: The whole system is common grounded. Vcc on the right hand side is the power supply of the RPi and the Vcc on the left hand side is the power supply of the rest of the circuit (both 5VDC.)

Tx1 and Tx2 is the input data for two serial bus drivers (MAX485).

Without isolation (direct wiring for data and command, and using one power supply for both RPi and the circuit), the system works fine.

[image]

Comment: How much is the VCC on LEDs on RPi side, 3.3V or 5V? If you are not using the optocoupler for isolation and MAX485 can work with 3.3V signals directly, why put an optocoupler in the first place? The 10k pull-up may be too high.

Comment: @ justme i'm trying to protect the Rpi because during tests when one of the MAX485 encounter any failure the program on the raspberry crash and the whole system stopped, i don't know why. so i thought to solve it by isolation is much easier of debugging the code

Comment: if the MAX485 has an issue and sends some data to RPi software that makes the system stop, it does not go away by optically coupling the exact same data waveform to RPi. But you did not answer the question. I hope you are not feeding 5V into RPi input, it will damage with 5V. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 115200 baud you have about 8us low and 8us high. From a [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf):

[image]

You would be better off to use a digital output optoisolator such as 6N137 if you really need that high a baud rate.

Comment: Slight mistake. For 115200 bps the time of bit period is 8.68us. There will be no 4us high and 4us low, at most, 8.68us high and 8.68us low.

Comment: @ Spehro would you please recommend a circuit diagram using 6n137 with component values. noting that i need the data not inverted

Comment: @Ezzat The 6N137 data sheet shows example values. But you should not need an optocoupler to begin with. Surely if MAX485 fails, then what does it matter if the RPi is sending data and the MAX485 doesn't react to that.

Comment: @Justme Thanks, fixed.